# Use of csv with php

Tags: csv, php-5.3

I have a requirement where I need to work my login form logic using a csv file. 'A' column in csv file has all Usernames and 'T' column has website names. Now the user logs in by typing in their usernames, and depending on that I have to redirect them to the website entered in column T. How will I use php to accompalish this?

```
A           T
ABC        www.test.com
DEF        www.test1.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) in order to read a line from a csv file. Have a look at the code below, it should cover your case:

```
$user = "test";
$file = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
$lines = explode("\n", $file);
while(($csv = fgetcsv($line, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
    // Assuming that string are separated by TAB instead comma
    if($csv[0] == $user) {
        header('Location: '.$csv[1]);
        exit();
    }
}
```

*Edit:* Code fixed. Wasn't working as fgetcsv requires a file handle to read from.

Answer (score 1):

```
$userSites = array();
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $userSites[$data[0]] = $data[1];
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Should create an associative array of users and the sites they should go to.